# Wordpress Custom Post Type Permalinks dynamic term slugs

Tags: custom-post-types, permalinks

I have a custom post type registered called `Resource`:

```
$args = array(
    'public' => true,
    'publicly_queryable' => true,
    'capability_type' => 'post',
    'hierarchical' => false,
    'supports' => array('title', 'thumbnail'),
    'register_meta_box_cb' => null,
    'taxonomies' => array(),
    'has_archive' => false,
    'rewrite' => array('slug' =>    'resources'),
    //'rewrite' => array('slug' =>    'resources/%term%'),
    //'cptp_permalink_structure' => '%term%',
    'query_var' => true,
    'can_export' => true
);
register_post_type('resource', $args);
```

I have these sub-categories under `Resource`:

```
Name         Slug
---------------------
eBooks       ebook
Brochures    brochure
Podcasts     podcasts
```

My question is, the post under `Resource` will have permalink like:

```
http://myurl.com/resources/post-name-1
```

I want to change the url structure to become:

```
http://myurl.com/resources/ebook/post-name-1
http://myurl.com/resources/brochure/post-name-2
http://myurl.com/resources/podcasts/post-name-3
```

I use the plugin [Custom Post Type Permalinks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CyxvS.jpg), in the setting page, I confuse how to use the `%slug%` before `/%postname%`, so that the permalink will looks like above samples

[image]

I need someone to guide me how can I achieve this.

Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to [wordpress.se]. I hope you find the answer(s) you are looking for. Our site is different from most - if you have not done so yet, consider checking out the [tour](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/tour) and [help center](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help) to find out how things work.